# Android - Send Email using JavaMail and OAuth2

Tags: java, android, email

I'm developing a basic email sender app that sends emails only to Gmail. After some time i figured out the hole scheme of the OAuth2 that Google now requires for authentication using the `getToken()` method from the `GoogleAuthUtil` API.

I've searched on the web for the JavaMail code to send the email using the token that i retrieve from the API and i found the following code that i'm using now:

```
package com.provider;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.URLName;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import android.util.Log;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64EncoderStream;

public class GMailOauthSender {
private Session session;

private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private int port = 587;
private String user;   
private String password;   



public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail,
        String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
    session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(debug);


    final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
    SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
    // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
    final String emptyPassword = null;
    transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

            byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail,
            oauthToken).getBytes();
    response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

    transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response),
            235);

    return transport;
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user,
        String oauthToken, String recipients) {
    try {

        SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com",
                587,
                user,
                oauthToken,
                true);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
                message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));   
                message.setSubject(subject);   
                message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());   


    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the code simply does not work. I've been sticked with this for more than three weeks and nothing so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

It was real pain when I did this first time and to make it work..Follow these steps

First you need to setup OAuth2 for your app in developer console, go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect) for details

Now you need to add these 4 files, these will help to send mail in background. When users open the app users will be shown a consent screen(Code in file AUthActivity.java) and will have to allow the app to use gmail, this is one time activity and not required later. When doing this user is requesting a token from google servers and will be saved in preferences so that users is not asked again(AuthPreferences.java). After user approves it you can send mail using:

```
GMailSender gMailSender = new GMailSender();
gMailSender.sendMail("hi", "hi", authPreferences.getUser(), authPreferences.getToken(), "somemailid@gmail.com");
```

Link for the files in github: https://gist.github.com/ranjithnair02/1c6dab7dec51971abfec

You also need to add the below jar files to your project:

http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar

http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar

http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar

You also need to add the following in Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```